# How to authenticate with LinkedIn API using 2-legged authentication?

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api

Basically, I want to authenticate with the LinkedIn app with the 2-legged type to get access to LinkedIn APIs like Jobs. But the issue is that you cannot set the 2-legged type from the LinkedIn app directly.

For more details, I attached all the guidance from Microsoft on LinkedIn APIs.

- Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext
- Get Token API: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
- Target API: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/jobs

I'm attempting to obtain a token using the Client Id and Secret provided by the LinkedIn App. I expected to get access from Two-Legged Flow, as the documentation explained on Microsoft Learn. The result the Get Token API returned was access denied with response code 401.

Comment: Is there an error message with the 401? There are some explanations of error codes and what they mean here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow#api-error-details.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue

My LinkedIn-App has the status "*verified*" and I added the Products "*Share on LinkedIn*" and "*Sign In with LinkedIn*", so the **OAuth 2.0 scopes** in the "Auth"-Tab are:

- r_emailaddress
- openid
- profile
- r_liteprofile
- w_member_social
- email

If I POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken with the app credentials, I get **401** too

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

@Ahmed J.

Do you get a solution what we have to do, that the app is allowed to create a token?

Comment: looks like as of 2023 `v2` is now `rest` in the URL. Hard to find, but multiple confirms in research.